# Let's discuss the logo and background for Esperanto.SE

Tags: discussion, design

Just like any other Stack Exchange site, Esperanto.SE should have an attractive logo and background design.

My suggestions:

- The *Verda Stelo* offers itself as a logo: It's simple, easily recognisable as a symbol of Esperanto, clearly stands out and can also be distinguished when it is drawn very small in the SE selection panel on the top right.
- The background should probably be a neutral, along with some sort of world map/globe. An idea would be to use something similar to the background on [travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com): a very faint hexagon-style world map.

What are your thoughts on this? What other suggestions are there?

Comment: I'm cusious, how do you even configure it?

Comment: @Zuoanqh It's Stack Exchange that changes the design of Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: It has recently been documented what can be customized in the new responsive SE designs: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319274/285037